# Translate email messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to translate email messages. I have a method in my model which is called after_save. This method creates mailer:

```
MyMailer.delay.notify_on_new_object self
```

The mailer uses mail message to send it:

```
mail(to: @email, subject: t(:subject, scope: "mailers.object"))
```

The problem is that every time english version of email is sent. No matter which locale is set in request. I know that request informations are not passed to models. So how can I set proper locale from request before sending email?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
I18n.locale = :es # or a locale variable given to the mailer
mail(to: @email, subject: t(:subject, scope: "mailers.object"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I can pass locale from request to mailer because I call mailer in model no after_save.